# how to make change the order of items in dropdownlist of nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

We are creating a web application in nopcommerce 3.8.in which we are doing some custom codes.but we are stuck at changing the order of dropdownlist in product add page.
Now while adding a product in dropdownlist first item is simple product and second product is grouped product,i want to change it so that first one is grouped product and second one is simple product.

view have the following i found

```
<div class="form-group @(Model.ProductEditorSettingsModel.ProductType ? null : "advanced-setting")">
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.ProductTypeId)

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">

                        @Html.NopDropDownListFor(model => model.ProductTypeId, ((ProductType)Model.ProductTypeId).ToSelectList())

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductTypeId)

                    </div>
                </div>
```

please provide me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Nop.Core\Domain\Catalog\ProductType.cs and change the order of items. It should look like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Grouped (product with variants)
    /// </summary>
    GroupedProduct = 10,
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple
    /// </summary>
    SimpleProduct = 5
```

Comment: I have tried to change enum order, it doesn't affect order of drop down items

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with rebuild solution but was not work!